# Is there a way to quantify the amount of spread of a plot of mean values over time?

Tags: time-series, variance, mean, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

I have a plot that is a mean of multiple measures of a motion over time with error bars 1 standard deviation away on the positive and negative side, which are calculated for each time point. I am looking for a statistical measure that can give me the amount of spread over the whole length of time to describe the variability.

The below plot displays the means of the knee angle for a number of gait cycles. The mean, standard deviation, and variance were all calculated for each time point. The blue line is the mean for each time point and the red lines are 1 standard deviation for that specific time point away from the mean.

[image: Example of Mean plot with error bars]

Essentially I want a way to quantify that this plot for example has less spread than a similar plot in which the error bars are further from the mean. If you see that they are further, you can tell that is the case, but I want to quantify that visualization.

I have found the average variance over time, by summing the variances calculated for each time point and then taking the mean. Subsequently I found the average standard deviation by taking the square root of the average variance. Is this measure meaningful and does it show what I am trying to find? If not, is there any measure that does?

Comment: At the outset you refer to "1 standard deviation."  That would be a single *number* and seems to be consistent with the constant (vertical) width of the bands in your plot. Could you therefore clarify what you mean by the "variances" (plural) and how they are computed?

Comment: so for every point on the blue mean plot, I calculated the mean, variance and standard deviation at that exact time for a number of motions (~30 gait cycles). The standard deviation varies depending on the time point, for example at around 75 the width is smaller than towards the beginning. The "variances" are the variance values for every individual time point

Comment: Please edit your post to include that essential information.  In light of it, what exactly does your plot show?  Are the bands based on these individual variances or on some global variance?  One issue will be *how much* the variances change: a relatively large amount of change is to be expected even with homoscedastic (constant-variability) responses. If indeed there are meaningful changes in variance, then please explain what a single "amount of spread over the whole length" would even represent.

Comment: Added additional context to the main post, but essentially I'm looking for a way to quantify the spread when compared with other plots in which the bands are wider. As for this specific plot, the bands are the individual standard deviations.